# Euler characteristic and free action

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $K$ is a finite simplicial complex, and $G$ acts simplicialy on $K$ with no fixed points, show $\chi(K) = |G|\cdot\chi(K^2/G)$.

Could I have a hint for how to start this question? I was told to barycentrically subdivide but I'm having trouble picturing the action of $G$.

Comment: What action of $G$ on $K^2$ are you considering?

Comment: Given that $G$ must be finite in order to act simplicially with no fixed points, and must also be a discontinuous action, we get that $K\to K/G$ is a covering map via the usual projection, and so $\chi(K)=|G|\cdot\chi(K/G)$ in the usual way for fiber bundles. As Olivier said though, I do not know where $K^2$ has come from or what the action of $G$ is on this space.

Comment: what is the usual way and projection? I'm not familiar with fiber bundles.